# iOS ARView and MTKView - how to restore camera position?

Tags: ios, arkit, swift5, metal, point-clouds

I have an iOS point cloud app and am trying to allow the user to keep adding points to an existing point cloud across multiple sessions.

I have a Metal MTKView, overlaid and aligned with an `ARView` underneath. When I have the `.showSceneUnderstanding` enabled, I can verify the point cloud of the metal view matches the mesh of the `ARView`.

I can restore the world state of ARView by archving and unarchiving of `ARWorldMap` and assigning it to `initialWorldMap`. After some device rotation, the scene will match the anchors from the ARWorldMap, and display appropriate scene understanding. I also have a point cloud, which is defined by XYZ.

**How can I get the camera within my MTKView to correspond to the current camera orientation within ARView?**

In other words, I can restore existing world map, and have it displayed, but have the ARView display the scene from a different, non-original viewport and camera position. When I restore the point cloud, the origin is set to the current device position/orientation, and the point cloud loses alignment with the real world.

How can I take ARView/ARWorldMap/ARFrame camera position and orient my point cloud, so my viewport within MTKView will correctly display the part of a point cloud which corresponds to this viewport of `ARView` ?

```
arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)

func preloadWorld(for configuration: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration) {
    
    guard let restoredMap: ARWorldMap = GeometryManager<ARWorldMap>().value else {
        return
    }
    configuration.initialWorldMap = restoredMap
    
    // 
}
```

Here's the code which captures the camera position:

```
static func create(with frame: ARFrame, viewportSize: CGSize) -> PointCloudUniforms {
var uniforms = PointCloudUniforms.defaults

uniforms.viewportWidth  = Float(viewportSize.width)
uniforms.viewportHeight = Float(viewportSize.height)

let screenOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait

let camera = frame.camera
let cameraIntrinsicsInversed = camera.intrinsics.inverse
let viewMatrix = camera.viewMatrix(for: screenOrientation) //TODO: pass in orientation

let viewMatrixInversed = viewMatrix.inverse
let projectionMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix(for: screenOrientation,
                                               viewportSize: viewportSize,
                                               zNear: 0.01,
                                               zFar: 100.0)

uniforms.viewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix
uniforms.localToWorld = viewMatrixInversed * screenOrientation.rotationToARCameraMatrix
uniforms.cameraIntrinsicsInversed = cameraIntrinsicsInversed

uniforms.cameraResolution = Float2(Float(frame.camera.imageResolution.width), Float(frame.camera.imageResolution.height))

return uniforms
}
```

Here's the shader which rotates each point cloud point based on the current camera position.

```
/// This is what is displaying an individual point in the point cloud
vertex ParticleVertexOut particleVertex(uint vertexID [[vertex_id]],
                                        constant PointCloudUniforms &uniforms [[buffer(kPointCloudUniforms)]],
                                        constant ParticleUniforms *particleUniforms [[buffer(kParticleUniforms)]]) {
    // get point data
    const auto particleData = particleUniforms[vertexID];
    const auto position = particleData.position;
    
    // animate and project the point
    float4 projectedPosition = uniforms.viewProjectionMatrix * float4(position, 1.0);
    
    projectedPosition /= projectedPosition.w;
    
    ParticleVertexOut out;
    out.position = projectedPosition;
    
    out.color = float4(particleData.color, 1);
    return out;
}
```

See example below Aligning a teapot with it's mesh from ARView.
[image]